# Blazor SQLite not reflecting on live server

Tags: azure, sqlite, blazor-server-side

I have a blazor application with an SQlite Crud system.

On the development environment it works fine, but when Publishing on Azure database does not reflect. Only two values are shown but with no value number assigned to them.

I have followed the below tutorial for Publishing my site: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=HNsBe3Cuu9g&t=2569s

Live Server

[image: live server]

Displaying the values on Index page on Live server

[image: live]

Development

[image: dev]

Displaying the values on Index page on development

[image: deevv]

Answer (score 0):

Right-click on my Databse file:

[image]

Click Publish

[image]